# CSS Percentage width isn't exact

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0. and the Isotope plugin ( masonry display and sorting ).
I think neither of these matter really.

my code is

```
.pf-container {
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
}

.pf-item {
    width:20%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

I've tried container with and without inline-block. i think what the problem here is that the 20 percent aren't exact. The body width is 1903px and divide that by 5 and you get 380,6.
When i inspect the `.pf-item` i find out that it's width is 381px. And that makes a problem, i want five pf-items in one row. Yet there are four and the next one is put in the next row. Because the total width of these five items is 1905px which is more than the body width. How do i fix this?

Comment: Welcome to the world of rounding errors. The opening lecture will be given by an Excel user.

Comment: where is the jsfiddle?????

Comment: There's no way to fix this? So my container has to be dividable by the number of items i want to have in one row? Sucks

Comment: Working in Software sucks too :P ..

Comment: If anybody would please have the patience to visit this link :

Comment: http://north.goldeyestheme.com/north/index3.html#portfolio it works there.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `bootstrap` which have a great Grid system where you can make multiple eqaul column. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zudebige/1)**.

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">Hello</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">I</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">am</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">the </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">Best</div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi there, i am using bootstrap but these columns have to be margin-less and padding-less. One next to the other. And implement that into bootstrap is a pain. And this is much easier.

Comment: by default these columsn have 15px padding. so removing this padding may solve your problem.

Comment: I'm sticking with my version for a lot of reasons one of which is simplicity. But if you would be so wise to explain to me, if both versions work with percentages then how would this work and my version wouldn't?

Comment: What code I've shared with you is provided by bootstrap, so if you are working with bootstrap then I hope you are fine with this code.